# Allow flutter Column to take all the available Space in this kind of layout

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-column

I've a ListView.builder on my page which wraps Columns inside it according to various parameters.

My code looks something like this :

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: sortedList.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    Render Column 1,
    Render Column 2,
    Render Column 3
}
```

My columns look something like this :

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
   Child 1,
   Child 2,
  ]
)
```

What I want ?
Now coming over to Column 3, I want it's one child to show at the top and one at the bottom of the screen. Something like this:
[image]

As you can see, **I want Column 3 to take all the page's available space and then it can align one of its child to the top and one to the bottom inside itself**. I can do this by simply adding MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween but right now I don't know how can I allow this Column to take all the available space inside of this ListView.

Can anyone please tell me what we can do here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fill the remaining spacing, you may need to use CustomScroll, some sliver widgets that fit you and **SliverFillRemaining** which is use to fill the remaining spacing of the scroll view. You may try the following example on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ef74afa80e041d251146c5f09f9ea185)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
        [
          Container(color: Colors.red, height: 50.0),
          Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 75.0),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: false,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text('remaining'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. How do i put itemExtent dynamically ? I mean just in case I don't want to give it a fixed height ? The Column 1 changes based on user parameters. It could be 10 px in height or 100 px in height.

Comment: You can try to use the SliverList and SliverChildListDelegate for dynamic height Column 1 and 2. I updated the example, you may check.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't rely on the list view, you can use this approach:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: Builder(
  builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      ),
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text('Column1'),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text('Column2'),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text('Column 3 child 1'),
                    Text('Column 3 child 2'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
));
```